# Define task for all projects which depends on project-level settings

Tags: sbt

I have a large SBT project with many sub-projects. I would like to add a task that I can run for any project that depends on project-level settings (like `name`).

In the following example, I've defined a task `myTask` which just prints the project's name:

```
name := "test-project"

val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("")

ThisBuild / myTask := {
  println((ThisProject / name).value)
}

val foo = project

val bar = project
```

My intention is to be able to run either `sbt foo/myTask` or `sbt bar/myTask` and have the same task executed but with corresponding project's settings taken into account. But if I do that with the project definition above, I get `test-project` printed irrespectively.

What is the intended way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `AutoPlugin` that needs be located in `project` folder

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object TestPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("Prints project name")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    Seq(myTask := { println(name.value) })
  }
}
```

It will be automatically enabled because of `allRequirements` and no dependencies, and thus `myTask` will be attached to all sub-projects defined in `build.sbt`

```
val foo = project

val bar = project
```

You can test this with commands `sbt "foo/myTask"` and `sbt "bar/myTask"` that print `foo` and `bar` respectively.